# std::_Xout_of_range Error when accessing value by key in map

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, stdmap

I have a problem that I really don't get. Maybe I didn't understand some basics of C++, which I actually thought I did. I basically only want to get a pointer to a set out of a map:

```
map<string, set<string>*>* ma = WindowCollection::testCase->getItems();
string te = ui->labelLeftUp->text().toStdString();
set<string>* itemSet = ma->at(te);
```

When debugging I get the following error in line 3:

Exception at 0x7ff83de9a1c8, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in MSVCP120D!std::_Xout_of_range

Exception at 0x7ff83de9a1c8, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in MSVCP120D!std::_Xout_of_range

This says that the requested set isn't in the map under the given key. Here are my variables from the debugging view, when the exception is thrown:

[image]

I really don't get it. te "Ich" obviously is a key in ma. What's the problem? Also going one step deeper into map:

```
mapped_type& at(const key_type& _Keyval)
        {   // find element matching _Keyval
        iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
        if (_Where == this->end()
            || this->_Getcomp()(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
            _Xout_of_range("invalid map<K, T> key");
        return (_Where->second);
        }
```

[image]

The exception is thrown in the last line. It's the same. Keyval "Ich" has a value assigned and ist represented by the key value pair 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method is good when you sure the key exists in the map. It's not the case here. On the screenshots above the key value in the map is **"Ich"**, but the value of the `te` variable is **"Ich "**.

Space at the end of `te` variable is the reason of the problem.

You can use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) or [`std::map::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) to check if the key exists in the map.